# How to deploy deep learning models in cloud?

Tags: python, azure, keras

I have built a deep learning model with python using keras (LSTM classifier for emotion speech recognition) and it's works perfectly locally, but when i load the model or pass an audio to classify i got a high memory usage (no problem so far, because i have 16GB in my machine).
I trying to deploy my model to Azure inside a flask web application and my question is: I will need a "super machine" in cloud to for run my model or there is a other method to deploy it reducing the costs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider leveraging [Azure Machine Learning](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/machine-learning/) service (PaaS). It has a pay-as-you-go pricing model (per hour). Refer [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/details/machine-learning/) for pricing based on your needed machine size. Also refer [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/machine-learning/).